# How can i get the value from table row?

Tags: php, html

This is the table form which i will select the row to edit by using Button Edit

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_document LIMIT $start, $end";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
echo "<table border='1' width='300' height='160' align = center id='result'>";
echo '<tr>
     <th width="80">ID</th>
     <th width="200">Title</th>
     <th width="260">Presented To</th>
     <th width="260">Presented By</th>
     <th width="160">Date Submitted</th>
     <th>Location</th>
     <th width="17%">Option</th>
</tr>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr align = center >";
    echo "<td width='20' height='60'>" .$row['ID']. "</td>";
    echo "<td width='120' height='60'>" .$row['Title']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['Presented_To']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['Presented_By']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['Date_Submitted']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['Location']. "</td>";
    echo "<td width='17%'>";
?>
<p>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('edtID').style.display='block'" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-border-large w3-circle" id="edit" name="edit" style="width:60%"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Edit</button>
```

This is the second code this form is modal which i click the button from the table and the modal show and you can edit but what is missing of my code?

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<p>
<label class="w3-label w3-text-black"><strong>Title:</strong></label>
<input class="w3-input w3-hover-light-blue w3-animate-input w3-border-large w3-light-grey" style="width:100%" type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" value=<?php $row['Title']; ?>required></span>
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Which value from a table row

Answer (score 0):

On your second form (your modal), I see no echo to display the value of your **title**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<p>
<label class="w3-label w3-text-black"><strong>Title:</strong></label>
<input class="w3-input w3-hover-light-blue w3-animate-input w3-border-large w3-light-grey" style="width:100%" type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" value=<?php echo $row['Title']; ?>required></span>
</p>
</form>
```

Also, for your first form, you can write it this way

```
<table border='1' width='300' height='160' align=center id='result'>
  <tr>
     <th width="80">ID</th>
      <th width="200">Title</th>
      ...
  </tr>

  <?php

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
       echo "<tr align = center >";
       echo "<td width='20' height='60'>" .$row['ID']. "</td>";
       echo "<td width='120' height='60'>" .$row['Title']. "</td>";
       ...
  ?>

  <p>
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('edtID').style.display='block'" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-border-large w3-circle" id="edit" name="edit" style="width:60%">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Edit
      </button>
   </p>

  <?php

  }

  ?>
```

**And finally, you should start using PDO for everything related to the database.**